# How to use apache UIMA audio annotator

Tags: apache, uima

Can anyone provide documentation for audio to text annotator for apache UIMA. 
I have really got confused.i am beginner for  UIMA.

Comment: Proove me wrong, but most people use UIMA to process text (even though it supports audio and other medium).

Answer (score 0):

If you are new to UIMA I would recommend to start from the beginning to get a better understanding of what UIMA is and how it works. The UIMA website has good documentation in this regards.

The SDK doesn't supply a sample, but does explain how to create your own. This is detailed in Chapter 5 of "[Tutorials and Users Guide](http://uima.apache.org/d/uimaj-2.4.2/tutorials_and_users_guides.pdf)" book.

The short answer though is that it doesn't by itself annotate audio. Instead it is a framework to allow you to create/work with annotations. So you would need to create your own annotator in the framework for the audio. I personally am not aware of one, but someone might link a third party annotator.